# how to split a string and fill a dynamic table with the values inside that string in adobe livecycle?

Tags: javascript, adobe, livecycle, livecycle-designer

I have a text that is a combination of values separated with commas "," and I want to split it and fill some column inside a table with those values.

I tried this code in the `indexChange` event of the table row:

```
var raw = this.EXTKD.rawValue.split(',');
this.EXTKD.rawValue = raw[this.index];
```

knowing that EXTKD is the name of the cell that I want to fill with the value, and it is intially filled with the whole text that I want to split.

when I try the above code only the first row gets filled.

Comment: since EXTKD ist just one cell, you can't expect all cells of one column to be filled - you need to fill raw values of all cells in that column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simply created another edit text called `EXTKDraw` to hold the raw value and hide it from the form view and I just modified my code to be called in the `ondocready` event like this:

```
var raw = EXTKDraw.rawValue.split(',');
this.EXTKD.rawValue = raw[this.parent.index];
```

where `this.parent.index` represents the index of the row of the table.